# Boost thread questions

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I am trying to do the followings

```
class a{
public:
  void Start();
  void Tick();
  bool IsTimeOut;
};

void a::Start()
{
  boost::thread thread1(boost::bind(&a::Tick,this));
}
void a::Tick()
{
  while(!IsTimeOut)
  {
    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::millisec(1000));
  }
}
```

My environment is vs2005 and win7.

However, I always got the access violation in the debug.

Comment: Your thread probably keeps running after the object has been destroyed. Post your complete test so that we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

An access violation in this case would indicate that the thread is running beyond the lifetime of the `a` object.

`IsTimeOut` needs to either be atomic or protected by a mutex if it is written by another thread, otherwise your program might not work correctly, but this shouldn't cause the access violation.

You are destroying the `boost::thread` object immediately, and thus detaching the thread, so you have no way of waiting for it to finish. I would suggest storing the thread object as a member variable of `a`, and either joining with it in the destructor of `a` or providing an explicit `wait()` member function that joins with the thread.

Comment: I would too think that access a dead object is the cause of the problem here, and then no volatile keyword, synchronization or memory barriers in the world will change anything.

Answer (score 0):

`IsTimeOut` should be `volatile` if accessed from multiple threads, i.e.

`volatile bool IsTimeOut;`

Take a look at [this DDJ article](http://drdobbs.com/184403766).

If you show more of your code and also explain how the `IsTimeOut` is changed it might be easier to say what goes wrong. In general, it looks like you have multiple threads and the first creates `a`, but what does that thread do then? Will `a` go out of scope and thus be destroyed? If so, then the timer thread will for sure have an access violation as the object is no longer available.

Comment: volatile is both not necessary and not sufficient for multi-threading.

Comment: But if I change the "IsTimeOut" to while(1), it still happened.

Comment: @Maxim, sure, but it's considered a good practice. Without more information what he's doing, it's not clear what's going wrong. At least it's good to change things in a proper way.

Comment: @murrekatt: using `volatile` for threading is **BAD** practice, not good practice!

Comment: @Anthony: in the case of a bool which controls the loop?

Comment: @murrekat: worth pointing out that volatile fails in the light of multi-core CPUs and CPU cache. It might be fine with explicit thread affinity, but as a rule it isn't OK to rely on volatile

Comment: @Anthony, in this case volatile should be present as it might otherwise be optimized by the compiler and will not be seen to be changed by the timer thread even if it is changed.

Comment: @murrekatt: `volatile` is the wrong tool for the job. Either use an atomic variable (e.g. `std::atomic<bool>`), or protect the flag with a mutex. Anything else is relying on compiler- and platform-specific guarantees.

Comment: @murrekatt volatile will force the threads to read/write memory instead of caching it in a register for example, which is necessary. But nothing forces both thread to see the same view of that memory location. Writing to a memory location in one thread does not mean that another thread will *see* the change at any specific time, and maybe writes will be seen out of order. On 'x86' you don't really see this problem in most common cases so you get away with it, but that doesn't mean it's correct.

Comment: @JohnB: yes, I know this. I also see this kind of thing used in code bases I've been working with. I.e. a shutdown bool or ready or something like that which will be changed from another thread to affect a thread in a loop of some sort.

Comment: Sorry for being politically incorrect, but this is a lot of brainwashed comments. Soon as someone hears multi-threaded and volatile in the same post, they all go "nooo you can't use volatile for thread safety / synchronization". Well, who mentioned thread safety and synchronization in this post? There are many more issues when threading than that - threading can cause dangerous optimizations on many compilers and then volatile is the solution against that particular issue. But that doesn't mean it solves synchronization and instruction piping issues, those are entirely different things.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6995310/is-volatile-bool-for-thread-control-considered-wrong/6996259#6996259