# Cache coherence systems from a timing point of view

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture, cpu-cache, memory-barriers, mesi

When reading about cache coherence systems (e.g. MESI) I've not a clear understanding about the timing involved.

Consider the case in which a Core1 wants to write to a cache line in state MESI S on its local cache. The local cache controller has to initiate an RFO to invalidate that line on all other caches in the cache coherence domain.

I believe all cache transactions are actually based on a clock interval so in the clock interval in which the RFO takes place other Cores (e.g. Cores2) are *not* allowed to read that cache line from their local cache (even if before the RFO takes place that line was locally in S MESI state).

Can you help me in understanding how things works from a clock timing point of view ?

Comment: From [memory-barriers-force-cache-coherency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958375/memory-barriers-force-cache-coherency) it seems the invalidation queue may allow the Core2 to read stale values from that cache line.

Comment: From this paper [Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers](http://www.rdrop.com/users/paulmck/scalability/paper/whymb.2010.07.23a.pdf) I've a doubt about the sequence of events in section 3.3. To me bullet no.7 cannot happen before CPU 1 cache controller does not process the 'read & invalidate' message for cache line 'a' sent from CPU 0 (namely bullet no.8)